# Connect to oracle server in NSIS

Tags: oracle, connection, nsis

Like we can connect to SQL Server using MSSQL_OLEDB plugin, how can we connect to Oracle server in NSIS? Also what if Oracle server is on some remote machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle have OLEDB provider, but NSIS not have ORACLE_OLEDB plugin.
You can connect throughout ODBC, with this plugin http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsODBC_plug-in
and oracle ODBC drivers: 
for 10G: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odbc/index.html
for 11G: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html